# class definition for Javascript Objects in documentation

Tags: javascript, oop, documentation

I'm developing a javascript library, composed by a main object, that works as a static Class and contains various objects that do the same thing.
I am having trouble finding the best way to refer to the objects in the documentation, as i am using jGrouse and it refers to them as Classes, like:

```
public Class myLibrary
```

None of these objects and it's children will have any primitive type variables nor will have any factory pattern associated so, they are not to be reinstantiated.

I can't show you a live example, but i'll try to put here an analogous one:

```
var myLibrary = {};
myLibrary.methodOne = function(){ ... };
myLibrary.methodTwo = function(){ ... };

// this is a sub-library that will encapsulate methods for Array type operations
 myLibrary.Array = {};
 myLibrary.Array.forEach = function(array, function(item));
 (...)

// this is a sub-library that will encapsulate methods for Event type operations
myLibrary.Events = {};
(...)
```

So, i don't think it's correct to refer to myLibrary, myLibrary.Array and myLibrary.Events as Classes, for the obvious reason that they are not meant to be instantiated.
I reject the idea to call them Static Classes as Javascript isn't design to work with static classes per se.
I think Object and Inner Object or Static Object may not be the way to go also.

I'm looking for the best way to identify them in my public documentation, as for not to confuse unexperienced programmers nor insult the more advanced developers.

Any help?
thanx

Comment: Your looking for the term "namespace". I wouldn't bother naming them at all, just document the methods for Array and Events.

Comment: what do you think about the term "module" used in the YUI documentation? also, do u want to put that as an answer so i can accept it? thanx

Comment: Everything is a "module" ;). Terminology like this is far too vague and should just be avoided. The important thing is to say "The Event <namespace/module/object> has these methods" the name you choose is irrelevant

Comment: ok, thanks. now let me give you the points, and post that as an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your probably looking for the term "namespace".

You really shouldn't worry so much about the correct word. The are all far too vague and have completely separate meaning is several different meanings in JavaScript sub cultures.

The important thing to say in documentation is that "The Event  has these methods".

I want to see the method signatures, I want to see a high level description of what they do and I want to see an example.